# Gparted not working in live CD (usb)

Tags: 10.10, live-usb, gparted, live-cd

Using Ubuntu 10.10 live USB. When attempting to open gparted (`sudo gparted` in a terminal), its window gets stuck for a few seconds and disappears (I noticed that it closes when it's searching for `/dev/sda/` partitions). After a while a window appears telling gparted closed unexpectedly and asking me to restart it. Choosing this option has no effect.

Typing `sudo fdisk -l` in a terminal does show a list of the drives and partitons correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you list the partitions from the terminal with: sudo fdisk -l ?

Comment: i can list them, yes.

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it's because gparted tries to do something with the usb drive (which contains the system). When I plugged out the usb drive, gparted started.

Comment: [Stacktrace](http://paste.ubuntu.com/563198/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED. Just used gparted through fedora 14. It worked right there.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you open `gksu gparted` with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or `sudo gparted` on a terminal.

Comment: of course, i do.

Comment: sudo gparted worked for me!
Thank you aldomann