# GParted Closing When Applying Operations

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, live-usb, gparted, sd-card

Recently I've been trying to get Lubuntu 14.04 running off of a SD Card (the computer I'm running this on only has 1 GB of hard disk space). I've created and used "Live SD"'s like this with persistence before, but I needed more space. I checked out a number of sources (like [this one](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/)), and most of them recommended using GParted to create a separate "casper-rw" partition.

I usually use Windows 8.1 for most of my work, so I loaded up a Ubuntu 14.04 (not Lubuntu) virtual machine in VirtualBox. After managing to access the SD card in the virtual machine, I brought up GParted and followed the instructions (except I used ext4 instead of ext2). GParted gave me a number of warnings such as "Moving a partition might cause your operating system to fail to boot." that I hadn't seen mentioned in the tutorial. Finally, I clicked "Apply All Operations", and it asked me if I wanted to use FAT32. I chose yes. Seconds after this decision, the program closed altogether, followed with messages about hardware problems.

I figured that it was an issue with the way that VirtualBox was accessing the SD Card, so I decided to create an additional Live-USB with Lubuntu on it. I booted from this Live-USB, then inserted the SD card. I used GPartition again, and it gave me the same warnings. Finally, after choosing to use FAT32, the program simply shut down again, this time with no warning.

I found [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20624/gparted-not-working-in-live-cd-usb) suggesting that I simply use Fedora, though I don't think this really solves or explains the problem.

Is there a new way that I should be doing this? Is the tutorial simply outdated?

**UPDATE:** It appears that using GParted on Fedora works well, though it took an exceptionally long time even on my best computer. Will make sure to test this out on Ubuntu again later to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If GParted closes when an operation is applied, then that is not normal and sounds like a bug.

Can you try performing one step at a time and applying?  That will help to isolate what step is failing - the fat32 resize, or the ext4 file system create.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, both with `gparted` and `fatresize`. It seems to be a bug, specifically [bug #1313600](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1313600).

In the end, my solution was to format the USB drive manually and not use any move or resize operations for FAT32.

FYI, note that using the command-line tool `parted` to resize/move the partition doesn't work either, as it is not filesystem-aware and will corrupt your data ([see here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#resizepart)).